# How to change Orbit View on Windows Community Toolkit to arrange at the top instead of middle left center

Tags: c#, windows, math, uwp, windows-community-toolkit

So, I'm working on Pie Control with Orbit View from Windows Community toolkit.
[image: Pie Control?]

I tried to change the behavior of Orbit View to arrange item started at the top instead of at the left center.

Here is when Orbit View has only one item.
[image: Here]

I tried tracking it down and found the code that Orbit View used to arrange item. But the problem is that I know nothing about math and didn't know where to change the value :/ So, here is the code.

```
    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        var angle = 2 * Math.PI / Children.Count;

        var minDistance = 80;
        var maxDistance = Math.Max(minDistance, (Math.Min(finalSize.Width, finalSize.Height) - OrbitView.MaxItemSize) / 2);

        var elementsProperties = new List<OrbitViewElementProperties>();

        for (var i = 0; i < Children.Count; i++)
        {
            var element = Children.ElementAt(i);

            OrbitViewDataItem orbitViewDataItem = null;
            if (element is FrameworkElement)
            {
                orbitViewDataItem = ((FrameworkElement)element).DataContext as OrbitViewDataItem;
            }

            var d = orbitViewDataItem != null && orbitViewDataItem.Distance >= 0 ? orbitViewDataItem.Distance : 0.5;
            d = Math.Min(d, 1d);

            var distance = (d * (maxDistance - minDistance)) + minDistance;
            var x = distance * Math.Cos((angle * i) + (angle / 2));
            var y = distance * Math.Sin((angle * i) + (angle / 2));

            var x_normalized = (finalSize.Width / 2) + x - (element.DesiredSize.Width / 2);
            var y_normalized = (finalSize.Height / 2) - y - (element.DesiredSize.Height / 2);
            var point = new Point(x_normalized, y_normalized);

            element.Arrange(new Rect(point, element.DesiredSize));

            var elementProperties = new OrbitViewElementProperties()
            {
                XYFromCenter = new Point(x, y),
                DistanceFromCenter = distance,
                Element = element
            };
            elementsProperties.Add(elementProperties);

            if (ItemArranged != null)
            {
                var args = new OrbitViewPanelItemArrangedArgs()
                {
                    ElementProperties = elementProperties,
                    ItemIndex = i
                };
                ItemArranged.Invoke(this, args);
            }
        }

        ItemsArranged?.Invoke(this, new OrbitViewPanelItemsArrangedArgs() { Elements = elementsProperties });

        return finalSize;
    }
```

So, where do I change it to make it start putting the item at the top center (0 degree) instead of left center (270 degree)

Edit: I fork the project and remove all item to just a few control here: https://github.com/ray1997/WindowsCommunityToolkit/tree/ForJustR
The code I mention above is in here: https://github.com/ray1997/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/ForJustR/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/OrbitView/OrbitViewPanel.cs line 90

Answer (score 1):

```
var angle = 2 * Math.PI / Children.Count;
```

This looks like the angle is expressed in radians.

```
var distance = (d * (maxDistance - minDistance)) + minDistance;
var x = distance * Math.Cos((angle * i) + (angle / 2));
var y = distance * Math.Sin((angle * i) + (angle / 2));
```

and here it is used to calculate the x and y values for the elements.
Now adding 90° or `2 * Math.PI / 4` Radians will move it by 90°.

So that gets you

```
// offset the first element by 90°
var customOffset = 2 * Math.PI / 4;
var distance = (d * (maxDistance - minDistance)) + minDistance;
var x = distance * Math.Cos((angle * i) + (angle / 2) - customOffset);
var y = distance * Math.Sin((angle * i) + (angle / 2) - customOffset);
```

Comment: I tested the code. But it ended up with item start at below instead ._. (180•)

Comment: Ok interesting. I did not test it myself, because I have no access to this Pie Control. You can try subtracting the `customOffset` instead of adding it.

Comment: Well.. It kinda work on the first few item but then when 4th item added It tilted 45 degree from what I expected. And when at 8th item (maximum of my used. I won't add more than 8) It was tilted about 30 degreen from what I wanted.